# Find a if filename does not exist in array of variable names

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of zipped files that contains a `ZipArchive` and the zipped `filename as a String`. I also have a final list of filenames that I need to check with my List and if the files do not match with my final list of filenames they should be dumped from my zipped file list.

I under stand that may not be worded the best so let me try and explain with my code/pseudo code.

Here is my list:

```
List<ZipContents> importList = new List<ZipContents>();
```

Which has two parameters:

1. `ZipArchive` which is called `ZipFile`
2. `String` which is called `FileName`

`filenames` is the finale list of file names that I am trying to check my `ZipContents` list against.

Here is the start of what I am trying to do:

```
foreach (var import in importList)
{        
    var fn = import.FileName;

    // do some kind of lookup to see if fn would be List<String> filenames
    // If not in list dump from ZipContents

}
```

The commented out section is what I am unsure about doing. Would someone be able to help get me on the right track? Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I know I did not say this originally but I think that LINQ would be the much cleaner route to take. I am just not positive how. I am assuming that using `.RemoveAll(..)` would be the way I would want to go?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if (!filenames.Contains(fn)) {
    importList.Remove(import);
}
```

Alternatively, I believe you could use Linq to simplify this logic into just one line.

Edit:

Yes, you can just create a new list of just the ones you want, like this:

```
var newImportList = importList.Where(il => filenames.Contains(il.FileName)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to write. If this isn't your answer I believe it should get you on the right track.

Comment: I like the way that you solved my issue with doing `.Remove()`, but will this cause issue in my list if there are a lot of contents and then one gets removed and the order changes?

Comment: If you're going to be removing items from the list, then it's going to change no matter what you do.  Using .remove() should preserve the order, but just remove the item in question.  However, as was pointed out in another answer, this may cause problems by modifying the list you're iterating through in your foreach.  I would suggest that the better approach would be to use Linq, as in the code from my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line.  Just use LINQ to re-establish your list:

```
var filenames = new List<string> {"file1", "file2"};
var zipcontents = new List<ZipContents>
{
     new ZipContents {FileName = "file1"},
     new ZipContents {FileName = "file2"},
     new ZipContents {FileName = "file3"}
};

zipcontents = zipcontents.Where(z => filenames.Contains(z.FileName)).ToList();

//zipcontents contains only files that were in 'filenames'
```

Honestly, this is what LINQ was made for: querying data.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `importList` in reverse and remove items when not found in `filenames`.  Assuming you don't have too many items performance should be fine:

```
for (int i = importList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!filenames.Contains(importList[i].FileName))
    {
        importList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

You can't remove items from the list using a `foreach` because it modifies the collection, but you can do it with the construct in my example.